# kazam 1.5.3 not opening in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ppa, kazam

after installing kazam 1.5.3 it was downloaded and showing in software ,but it was not functioning.It shows in command line as

```
/usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system.
kazam 1.5.3 'NX-72307'
```

.In ubuntu software centre showing the the new version with
source `lp_ppa_sylvain_pineau_kazam-focal-main`

[image]

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same problem after updating from Ubuntu 18 to 20. Please let me know how it resolves for you!

Comment: I gave your question a bounty, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1):

It may mean that package from PPA is somekind wrong. You can remove it and install package from the official repository with terminal commands below

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: Didn't work for me ; (

Comment: You only specified the commands to remove the ppa. he might also need to reinstall it from the official repo. Please provide the `apt install` command

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. I had the same issue. I uninstalled Kazam and reinstalled it and it works like charm.

```
sudo apt purge kazam
sudo apt install kazam
```